# How to implement more than one Identity in ASP NET CORE 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Hi the first step of creating multiple identities is to inherit from IdentityUser and inherit from this inheritance like so:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Advertiser> Advertiser { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bagger> bagger { get; set; }
}
public class AppUser : IdentityUser {}
public class Advertiser : AppUser {}

public class Bagger : AppUser {}
```

But how do we arrange our Program.cs to use second identities in asp net core 6.0?

Comment: Why?! Instead of asking "How to implement more than one identity", you should first ask yourself: "Why do I think I need two identities [in a single application]?". Seems like you are asking the for the wrong solution for your problem

Comment: I agree with @Tseng, and another question is, if you want to provide several kinds of identities in your app, then what are they? For example, what kinds of accounts you want your uses to use to sign in? Google account? Microsoft account?